# Скрипт для определения устройства пользователя

Tags: javascript

Есть у кого-нибудь готовый скрипт js для определения устройства с которого пользователь просматривает страницу?
Необходимо определить устройство на ios (не важно планшет или айфон) и подключить стили css только для ios

Comment: [ответ ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova как у Вас получилось ответить на вопрос требующий правки?!

Comment: да, мой код работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделала так:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ) {
    $(".select-form .margin-left .param").addClass("ios-param");
    $(".select-form .margin-left input").addClass("ios-margin-left");
    $(".select-form .flex-itm .margin-right").addClass("ios-flex-itm");
}
```

Comment: и еще, новичку сложно понимать решение на английском языке. в будущем, да было бы полезно. но пока сложно...

Answer (score 1):

Использовал в этот для определения тач-девайсов:

```
isTouchDevice = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|playbook|silk|BlackBerry|BB10|Windows Phone|Tizen|Bada|webOS|IEMobile|Opera Mini)/);
// переменная будет "true" если используется тач-девайс
```

Думаю должно подойти.

Comment: _Необходимо определить устройство на ios_ - ваше решение неверно, вернее, вы решили другую задачу

Comment: @Grundy Я предоставил пример в котором перебираются все тач-устройства и чтоб получить желаемое мб нужно просто удалить лишнее?

Comment: я вообще думаю, стоило бы и ответ удалить, и если б можно было ставить дубликаты на английский вариант, я бы поставил. На данный момент - ваш ответ, не является ответом на вопрос, поэтому его стоит либо изменить, либо удалить

Comment: @Grundy пускай автор темы решает полезным ли оказался данный ответ или нет.

Comment: @Grundy и вместо того чтоб спорить, могли бы предоставить свой, на 200% идеальный ответ.

Comment: я и предоставил ссылку на абсолютно идентичный вопрос

Comment: ваш вариант абсолютно понятен, спасибо! возьму себе на вооружение)

Comment: @Grundy, в следующий раз всем будет гораздо полезнее, если вы опубликуете перевод, сохранив ссылку на оригинал.

Comment: @Nofate, ok, в следующий раз